# Inserting Multiple image FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I wanted to place an image in different location using cell

Here is part of my code :

```
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();

$pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $pdf->Image('../img/printing/LOGO.jpg',0,0,50,0,"","home.php"), 
      0, 'L');  //-->THIS PART IS WORKING

$x = 160;
$y = $y ;
$pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'asd', 0, 'L'); //-->THIS PART IS WORKING

$x = 160;
$y = $y;
$pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $pdf->Image('../img/printing/LOGO.jpg',0,0,50,0,"","home.php"), 
      0, 'L');  //-->THIS PART IS NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the point in `LOGOjpg`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware my bad, it's typo when edit code in posting. The code still not working.

Comment: Isn't your `$x` and `$y` is always the same? `$y = $y` is useless.

Comment: @Justinas yes, for now , in the future i can use it like `$y = $y + 10`.

Comment: @Kelpie Soo... Maybe your image is placed above your text (text is hidden by image)?

Comment: @Justinas That's what i thought, but i try to print it using normal string and it works fine in the location i wanted to be.

Comment: @Justinas turn out you are right, when i erase the first image print it still there because of the next image print. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have resolve the problem `$pdf->Cell(0, 0,asd $pdf>Image('../img/printing/LOGO.jpg', 0,0,50,0,"","home.php"),0,'L');` is not following the current position of the cell. so i must match it with the current position. `$pdf->Cell(0, 0,asd $pdf>Image('../img/printing/LOGO.jpg', 160,0,50,0,"","home.php"),0,'L');` as in full part of code below

```
$x = 160;
$y = $y;
$pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $pdf->Image('../img/printing/LOGO.jpg',160,0,50,0,"","home.php"), 
      0, 'L');  //-->THIS PART IS NOT WORKING
```